# Laptop not booting after OS install

Tags: windows, ubuntu, laptop, asus-laptop, repair

I installed Ubuntu on my Asus TP410u laptop but had to then revert to Windows 8.1.

I made a boot drive for the Windows installer and ran it; everything worked fine, until I connected my mouse and the screen went black. Now my laptop is stuck in what seems to be (by the led indicator) sleep mode.

There's also no fan or disk noise and no sign of a POST check.

Comment: unplug the power cord and remove the battery. Count to 10. reinstall the battery and plug in the power cord. hit the power button.

Comment: It's fundamentally not possible to "brick" a PC unless you corrupt the BIOS/UEFI firmware... bricking refers to corrupting the bootloader (hard[ware] brick) or the system/firmware image (soft[ware] brick) on embedded devices _(terminology matters when seeking help or describing a problem)_. The only thing I would add to @Larryc's recommendation is to discharge the capacitors by repeatedly pressing the power button for 30s once the battery is removed.